# Wedding seating chart combinations

Tags: probability

Given the example problem described [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiXwOvur7PhAhWRonEKHfqTABAQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.improbable.com%2Fnews%2F2012%2FOptimal-seating-chart.pdf&usg=AOvVaw20dsaKSK9IiD6O8azp0z7c) at page 2:

Example Problem

> Take a small wedding consisting only of the immediate family. There are 17 guests total
>   (assume the bride and groom sit at their own sweetheart table) and since each table can seat 10 guests, only
>   two tables are necessary. Let us also say that each guest must know at least one other people at their table.
>   So m = 17, n = 2, a = 10, and b = 1.
>
> > where a the maximum number of guests a table can seat
> >     & b the minimum number of people each guest knows at their table
>
> There are $2^{17}$= 131,702 possible combinations for seating these guests.

How is the $2^{17}$ number of combinations derived?

Comment: Bounty added,lets see.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit misleading I think. It seems to me that they have just done the following.

Every guest can choose between table $a$ or table $b$. i.e. have two choices. So this will give the total number of possibilities as $2^{17}$. But this number does not respect all the conditions in the problem. e.g. there can only be $10$ guests at every table.

In the next example there is also an error where they write

"The number of possible combinations is $4^{17} = 7.63 × 10^{11}$"

The $4$ here is supposed to be a $5$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, you re right, this is what perplexed me. The 15th guest, for example, would only ever have one choice, not 2 etc. Just trying to see if there is something I'm missing in regards to this or some type of formula(im unaware) can be simplified to get this result.